# can the three.js EventDispatcher be used to communicate between classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, three.js, assign, event-dispatching

#### Core question

An event emitted on one class that supports EventDispatcher doesn't get picked up by another class that supports EventDispatcher.

How do I get the communication working app-wide so that I can pass messages around?

At the moment it seems that it only supports passing a message to its own class.

#### Background

I'm using this boilerplate which gives me three.js and es6:

https://github.com/paulmg/ThreeJS-Webpack-ES6-Boilerplate

I've updated the packages manually to use three.js r97.

I'm looking at the EventDispatcher class and I'm thinking this is a clean way for me to pass messages around the system while keeping it decoupled. For example, I have some HTML UI that watches a checkbox.

Trimmed down to the core example, I have interaction.js:

```
import {EventDispatcher} from 'three';

// Manages all input interactions
export default class Interaction {
  constructor() {
    // Add event dispatcher support
    Object.assign( this, EventDispatcher.prototype );

    // setup the trigger for the event
    let outer = this;
    $("#" + Config.uiElements.boxOpenStateId).change(function() {
      console.log("event emitting");
      outer.dispatchEvent( { type: 'boxOpenStateToggled', message: { isChecked: "example" } } );
      console.log("event emitted");
    });

    // setup a event listener
    this.addEventListener( 'boxOpenStateToggled', function ( event ) {
      console.log("event caught in Interaction.js", event);
    });
  }
}
```

And I have boxmanager.js (trimmed down to the core bits):

```
import {EventDispatcher} from 'three';

export default class BoxManager {
    constructor() {
        // Add event dispatcher support
        Object.assign( this, EventDispatcher.prototype );
    }

    setupBoxes(manager) {
        console.log("adding event listener on BoxManager.js");
        this.addEventListener( 'boxOpenStateToggled', function ( event ) {
            console.log("event caught by BoxManager.js", event);        
        } );
    }
}
```

When I trigger the `boxOpenStateToggled` event on `Interaction` the `BoxManager` event listener doesn't capture it.

I get a console log like this:

```
adding event listener on BoxManager.js
adding event listener on Interaction.js

(I trigger the event)

event emitting
event caught in Interaction.js {type: "boxOpenStateToggled", message: {…}, target: Interaction}
event emitted
```

What I was expecting here was to see "event caught in BoxManager" as well - is it a system-wide event dispatcher? Or can it only dispatch events internally on a per-class basis?

#### Showing my working

I wasn't sure if it was the way I was using it with so I have tried:

- using the `extends` keyword on the class to give the `EventDispatcher` functionality and it works but only within the class.
- using the `.call` version initially which was in an earlier release of three.js.

I can't find any real discussion or examples of using EventDispatcher or see where it is even used in the library.

Have I misunderstood its purpose? Am I using it wrong?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. `EventDispatcher` does that - dispatches events. Most of three's classes extend this class. You can use it outside of three, it's pretty generic. So sure, the answer is yes. But your question is more about the semantics of the language and patterns. In which case i don't quite know what this is, and i'd probably revisit this https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: @pailhead my confusion is that I have extended two classes to support event dispatcher and when I dispatch an event on one, it's not picked up on the other, even though I have a handler on it.

Comment: @pailhead I have updated my question to spell out my issues hopefully more clearly, thank you for your interest so far

Comment: Ok i think this isn't an issue with the `EventDispatcher` but how you're using JS. I'm a bit confused about this and would have to dig deeper but what you're doing with the prototype and `Object.assign` seems pretty weird. I don't think you're dispatching and listening to the same object.

Comment: Where do you call `new Interaction()`?

Comment: ` is it a system-wide event dispatcher? Or can it only dispatch events internally on a per-class basis?` Ah, no it is not. You can make it global yourself by following a pattern. Your other object has no knowledge of the event from the first one.

Comment: thanks this is what is was starting to think as well but I couldn't see much point in the `EventDispatcher` then when an internal function could easily call any other method on the class.

Comment: i have to admit i'm still confused about what you're confused about :) `EventDispatcher` is very useful simple class. Like i said, almost everything in three.js extends from it.

Comment: @pailhead thank you for sticking with me. What has confused me is taking a game example, input triggers an event "gun.shoot", audio classes handle "gun.shoot" and play a sound, physics handles "gun.shoot" and move the bullet and check for hits, gameplay class handles "gun.shoot" and decreases the ammo count, etc. Seemed like thats what this was, event based decoupling. 

But if the keyboard class can only say "gun.shoot" to itself then it seems a lot less useful and I'm wondering what its use cases are that I've missed.

Comment: I understand what you're looking for but it's in the realm of oop patterns which i don't command that well. My guess would be that this class out of the box is an `observer` pattern, while the global event bus (and what you're looking for) would be a `pub/sub`, but i might be totally wrong. It might be worth revisiting the addy osmani link (I will certainly do that).

Comment: From a logic standpoint i think i see a flaw in your request. So the audio class hangles `gun.shoot` but since there are many guns in the world, and some you should hear louder based on distance, how does that class know **which gun shot**? With three you would doo something like `new GunAudio( myGun )` and then inside of `GunAudio` you would subscribe to `myGun.addEventListener('shoot', this.onShoot)`. With pubsub (i think) it would be `Events.addEventListener('shoot', ({gun})=>{ this.onShoot(gun) }) )` if that makes sense?

Comment: I'll make an update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider doing something like this:

```
const myEventBus = new THREE.EventDispatcher()

const foo = new Foo(myEventBus)
const bar = new Bar(myEventBus)
```

If you want to avoid passing the instance to objects like this, or making factories, you could do something like this:

```
//Events.js
const Events = new THREE.EventDispatcher()
export default Events
```

And then:

```
//Foo.js
import Events from 'common/Events'
import {BOX_OPEN} from 'Bar'
export default class Foo {
  constructor(){
    Events.addEventListener( BOX_OPEN, this.onBoxOpen);
  }
}
```

Dispatch

```
//Bar.js

export const BOX_OPEN = 'box_open'

export default class Bar {
  constructor(){
    $("#" + Config.uiElements.boxOpenStateId).change(this.onChange);
  }
  onChange = () => {
     console.log("event emitting");
     Events.dispatchEvent({ type: BOX_OPEN, message: { isChecked: "example" } });
     console.log("event emitted");
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree this seems to be one way to use it but its confusing to me as it doesn't follow the example. The wierd prototype stuff I'm doing is the [setup from the three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent).

It seems that if it can only pass messages between that individual object then it's not very useful. It feels like we are both missing something as otherwise I dont know why it was implemented into three.js and documented that way.

Comment: Please notice that the example is using `prototype` you're assigning it to `this`.

Comment: In your case `Object.assign(Interaction.prototype, EventDispatcher.prototype)`

Comment: thanks for sticking with me for this one, this explains it exactly how I expected to use it, guess I just needed a bit more JavaScript knowledge to understand what I was looking at :)

Comment: No worries. I was mostly confused by the prototype thing but I’m not even sure if it would break it. But that wasn’t the problem.

Comment: hmm this didn't actually get my code working, I'm seeing the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined` even though im importing the event manager using the techniques you described. I guess I'm at the point now where I should just accept that I'm bending this in ways it's not intended to work. It looks like I should probably be putting my efforts into PubSubJs instead?

Comment: Hmm. Why do you keep coming to that conclusion? You can simply modify the constructor to take the global events object and try calling new eventdispatcher in your main file. It simply has to work. (This is the first snippet) Maybe I didn’t write the export syntax right.

Comment: But considering that you incorrectly copied the initial example, there’s a possibility that you did something wrong on your end. The fact that you’re calling a method on undefined is just that. It would fail in any other example that has nothing to do with events, dispatchers, lasers or ducks. If you can instantiate a dispatcher in one file and add a listener on it, it works. If you export from one module and import undefined in another the import/export is the thing that doesn’t work. Not the class that was exported, if that makes sense.

Comment: If you make your own simple object called Duck and make a method quack, you can replace your EventDispatcher with Duck and addEventLitener with quack. This should run with no errors. You can add a console log in the method and make sure that it works. If you import undefined and try to call quack() it will still fail, but you shouldn’t conclude that your duck can’t quack, just that you didn’t obtain the duck in the first place.

Comment: Did you import Events in all files?